# Is there a way to run BDD(Automation Test) on Dynamic Data(Keeps on changing) also previous data is getting wiped off in every 2 week?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd

I am running an angular application. I want to run automation testing on 3 different environment with different set of data.

Comment: Also The data is getting wiped off in every 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. you can externalize you data to json files and then require it in your tests, like so

```
let data = require("./path/to/your/data.json");
```

Comment: I want to run it with dynamic data which we will get from API Response. I don't want to run it with static data. Major issue i am having is server's data is getting wiped off in every 2 weeks.

Comment: so what is your question? how to get data from server? how to feed it to protractor? or how to store it IF/WHEN its wiped off?

Comment: So basically my application is making API calls and fetching data. I want to test the data and UI in automation scripts. I have issue with data because it its getting wiped off in every 2 week